# Binding of didTransition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I tried to bind didTransition to the function.

```
callGallery: ( ->
   console.log('inside callGallery')
).on('didTransition')
```

But don't work. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to call didTransition in controller, it started working when I called from routes file.